# How use spinner in fragment

Tags: android

I´ve tried call the spinner in the SesionFragment.java, but I don´t know how to do.

I have the following project which I seek to call the spinner in the SesionFragment.java and when clicking on the "login" button in the text of the selected spinner call another activity, for example when selecting Secretary call Activity3Main. java and when selecting Treasurer call Activity4Main.java etc.

[Data Base User, Password and Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXWbw.png)

fragment_sesion.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.josue.login.SesionFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/user_fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.105"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.189" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/pwd_fragment"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.177" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtuser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite su Usuario"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.287"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.178" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtpwd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite su Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.741"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtuser"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.127" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnsesion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
        android:text="@string/sesion_fragment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnregistrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/registrar_fragment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnsesion"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/simpleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/Cargo"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtpwd"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.061" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

SesionFragment.java

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SesionFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
    RequestQueue rq;
    JsonRequest jrq;
    EditText txtUser, txtPwd;
    Button btnSesion, btnRegistrar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sesion, container, false);
        txtUser = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
        txtPwd = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtpwd);

        btnSesion = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnsesion);
        btnRegistrar = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnregistrar);
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        btnSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iniciar_sesion();
            }
        });

        btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                registrar_usuario();
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecto " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inicio de Sesión Exitoso " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        User usuario = new User();
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            usuario.setUser(jsonObject.optString("user"));
            usuario.setPwd(jsonObject.optString("pwd"));
            usuario.setNames(jsonObject.optString("names"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
        intencion.putExtra(Main2Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
        startActivity(intencion);
    }
    void iniciar_sesion() {
        String url = "https://xxxxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx/inicio.php?user=" + txtUser.getText().toString() +
                        "&pwd=" + txtPwd.getText().toString();
        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
        rq.add(jrq);

    }

    void registrar_usuario(){
        RegistrarFragment fr=new RegistrarFragment();
        //fr.setArguments(fr);
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.escenario,fr)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
strings.xml

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Ipuc Sesion</string>

    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hermano(a), por favor digite sus datos</string>
    <string name="user_fragment">Usuario:</string>
    <string name="pwd_fragment">Contraseña:</string>
    <string name="sesion_fragment">Iniciar Sesion</string>
    <string name="registrar_fragment">Registrar usuario</string>
    <string name="names_fragment">Nombres: </string>
    <string-array name="Cargo">
        <item>Seleccione su Cargo</item>
        <item>Pastor</item>
        <item>Tesorero(a)</item>
        <item>Secretario(a)</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Ipuc Sesion</string>

    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hermano(a), por favor digite sus datos</string>
    <string name="user_fragment">Usuario:</string>
    <string name="pwd_fragment">Contraseña:</string>
    <string name="sesion_fragment">Iniciar Sesion</string>
    <string name="registrar_fragment">Registrar usuario</string>
    <string name="names_fragment">Nombres: </string>
    <string-array name="Cargo">
        <item>Seleccione su Cargo</item>
        <item>Pastor</item>
        <item>Tesorero(a)</item>
        <item>Secretario(a)</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4U5.png)

Comment: What problems did you encounter in your app?

Comment: How I call the spinner from SesionFragment.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem with this code:

```
package com.example.josue.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SesionFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {
    RequestQueue rq;
    JsonRequest jrq;
    EditText txtUser, txtPwd;
    Button btnSesion;
    Spinner _spinner;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sesion, container, false);
        txtUser = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtuser);
        txtPwd = (EditText) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtpwd);
        _spinner = (Spinner)vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.Cargo,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        _spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnSesion = (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.btnsesion);

        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        btnSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                iniciar_sesion();
            }
        });



        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return vista;
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuario - Contraseña y/o Cargo Incorrecto " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inicio de Sesión Exitoso " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        User usuario = new User();
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            usuario.setUser(jsonObject.optString("user"));
            usuario.setPwd(jsonObject.optString("pwd"));
            usuario.setNames(jsonObject.optString("names"));
            usuario.setRole(jsonObject.optString("role"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("pily") && txtPwd.getText
                ().toString().equals("1234") && _spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Tesorero(a)")) {

            Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            intencion.putExtra(Main2Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
            startActivity(intencion);

        } else if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("jair") &&
                txtPwd.getText().toString().equals("1234") && _spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Secretario(a)")) {

            Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
            intencion.putExtra(Main3Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
            startActivity(intencion);

        } else if (txtUser.getText().toString().equals("jose") &&
                txtPwd.getText().toString().equals("12345") && _spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("Pastor")) {

            Intent intencion = new Intent(getContext(), Main4Activity.class);
            intencion.putExtra(Main4Activity.nombres, usuario.getNames());
            startActivity(intencion);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Usuario - Contraseña y/o Cargo Incorrecto " + txtUser.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    void iniciar_sesion() {
        String url = "https://ipucsegundaalgarrobo.000webhostapp.com/inicio.php?user=" + txtUser.getText().toString() +
                "&pwd=" + txtPwd.getText().toString() + "&role=" + _spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
        rq.add(jrq);
    }


}
```

Comment: This solution function it for me.